# ASP.NET Core Web API controller with generic params

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API communicating with a flutter mobile app.

The feature I am adding is a notification service. The issue is I have more than one notification type.

Here is the code:

```
public class NotificationSuper 
{
    public string  Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class UnitNotification :NotificationSuper
{
    public String Renter_Key { get; set; }
    public String Owner_Key { get; set; }
    public String Building_Key { get; set; }
    public String Unit_Key { get; set; }
}

public class MaintenanceNotification : UnitNotification
{
    public DateTime RequestData { get; set; }    
}
```

and so on.

I wrote a controller for the notification using a super generic type in its params

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] NotificationSuper notification)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    bool success = await Notify.Send(notification);

    if (success)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    return StatusCode(500);            
}
```

**The problem** is when I retrieve the JSON data from the flutter app, I only get the properties of the `NotificationSuper` class which are:

```
public String Renter_Key { get; set; }
public String Owner_Key { get; set; }
public String Building_Key { get; set; }
```

I want to have a flexible way to get every property if I passed `UnitNotification` or `MaintenanceNotification`. Should I have multiple controllers, one for each type of notification?

Thanks in advance

Comment: From what I know the JSON is mapped to the class in action method but there are many way for the action to receive Dynamic type too but ,imo I will just overload the POST method to receive other classes then call to one private method that doing the operation.

Comment: @user3682728
I thought of making separate controllers for each model but I don't feel this way is the best way so I wanted some generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your `UnitNotification` and
`MaintenanceNotification`

It should look like this

```
public class CombinedNotification
{
    public UnitNotification unitNotification { get; set; }
    public MaintenanceNotification maintenanceNotification{ get; set; }
}
```

Then your controller code should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] CombinedNotification notification)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    bool success;

    if (notification.UnitNotification != null)
    {
         bool success = await Notify.Send(notification.UnitNotification);
    }

    if (notification.MaintenanceNotification != null)
    {
         bool success = await Notify.Send(notification.MaintenanceNotification);
    }

    if (success)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    return StatusCode(500);            
}
```

The important thing is your post data now must be changed from: `unitNotification` to `{"unitNotification": {}}`

Comment: thanks for you fast reply.
but i dont get the last part 

The important thing is your post data now must be changed from: unitNotification to {"unitNotification": {}}

Comment: @quang
when i send a Json like that 
{"Title": "Renting",
 "Body": "Someone wants to rent a unit",
  "Token":"fn9DlgYFTL2ueRVGXxS-BT:APA91bGVZtas4VwmxICgeyuwRbU-0qet8WTyXg3ct_cVB__OOQ1se9P3W70fy6dYfEAXu4lItN9Za9MzcC_s2A6AAqYMlkyAXsD36gQX2X93h9ciXHhSlt0hJHAYibEDrdzH5n6a2RNX",
   "Type": "Renting",
    "Renter_Key":"123456789124c@c.com", 
    "Owner_Key": "123456789123o@o.com",
     "Building_Key": "13st.2212345678", 
     "Unit_Key": "3333334200"
}
it does not instantiate any combinedNotification Object so all of them are null

Comment: Your post data should like this, 
{
  "UnitNotification": {
    "Title": "Renting",
    "Body": "Someone wants to rent a unit",
    "Token": "token",
    "Type": "Renting",
    "Renter_Key": "123456789124c@c.com",
    "Owner_Key": "123456789123o@o.com",
    "Building_Key": "13st.2212345678",
    "Unit_Key": "3333334200"
  },
  "MaintenanceNotification": {
    "Title": "Renting",
    "Body": "",
    "Token": "token",
    "Type": "Renting",
    "RequestData": "2022-06-15 12:00:00"
  }
}
Replace UnitNotification or MaintenanceNotification by null if you don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more flexible method, I use `Polymorphic model binding`, You can refer to this simple demo:

**Model**

```
public abstract class Device
{
    public string Kind { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Laptop : Device
{
    public string CPUIndex { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }
}

public class SmartPhone : Device
{
    public string ScreenSize { get; set; }
}
```

**Model Binding Code**

```
public class DeviceModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType != typeof(Device))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var subclasses = new[] { typeof(Laptop), typeof(SmartPhone), };

        var binders = new Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)>();
        foreach (var type in subclasses)
        {
            var modelMetadata = context.MetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(type);
            binders[type] = (modelMetadata, context.CreateBinder(modelMetadata));
        }

        return new DeviceModelBinder(binders);
    }
}

public class DeviceModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)> binders;

    public DeviceModelBinder(Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)> binders)
    {
        this.binders = binders;
    }

    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var modelKindName = ModelNames.CreatePropertyModelName(bindingContext.ModelName, nameof(Device.Kind));
        var modelTypeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelKindName).FirstValue;

        IModelBinder modelBinder;
        ModelMetadata modelMetadata;
        if (modelTypeValue == "Laptop")
        {
            (modelMetadata, modelBinder) = binders[typeof(Laptop)];
        }
        else if (modelTypeValue == "SmartPhone")
        {
            (modelMetadata, modelBinder) = binders[typeof(SmartPhone)];
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return;
        }

        var newBindingContext = DefaultModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext(
            bindingContext.ActionContext,
            bindingContext.ValueProvider,
            modelMetadata,
            bindingInfo: null,
            bindingContext.ModelName);

        await modelBinder.BindModelAsync(newBindingContext);
        bindingContext.Result = newBindingContext.Result;

        if (newBindingContext.Result.IsModelSet)
        {
            // Setting the ValidationState ensures properties on derived types are correctly 
            bindingContext.ValidationState[newBindingContext.Result.Model] = new ValidationStateEntry
            {
                Metadata = modelMetadata,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

**Notice:**  This demo needs data from **form**, If you need data from **request body**, You need to change some code in `DeviceModelBinder` And parent class needs a property to specify the class name of the subclass.

Refer to [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#polymorphic-model-binding).